# How do I populate a struct pointer with global struct reference inside a C function?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, struct, pass-by-reference

I am new to C and having trouble understanding why my_struct_ptr (main) is nil in the following example.  How would I assign the address of a struct in the my_structs array to the my_struct_ptr pointer within the get_my_struct_by_name function?

```
struct my_struct {
    char *name;
    char *descr;
    char *value;
} my_structs[3] = {
    {"a", "a description", "value 1"},
    {"b", "b description", "value 2"},
    {"c", "c description", "value 3"}
};

int get_my_struct_by_name(char *name, struct my_struct *my_struct_ptr) {

    int i;
    for (i=0; i < (sizeof(my_structs)/sizeof(struct my_struct)); i++) {
            if (strcmp(name, my_structs[i].name) == 0) {

                    my_struct_ptr = &my_structs[i];

                    printf("works: %s,%s,%s\n", my_struct_ptr->name, my_struct_ptr->descr, my_struct_ptr->value);
                    return 0;
            }
    }

    return -1;
}


int main() {
    int res = 0;
    struct my_struct *my_struct_ptr;

    if (res = get_my_struct_by_name("b", my_struct_ptr))
            return res;

    printf( "nil: %p\n", my_struct_ptr);

    printf("seg fault: %s,%s,%s\n", my_struct_ptr->name, my_struct_ptr->descr, my_struct_ptr->value);

    return res;
}
```

Edit:  Adding example output to hopefully help others.  Thank you to everyone who responded.  This is exactly the help I was looking for!

Output:

```
[prompt ~]$ ./test
works: b,b description,value 2
nil: (nil)
Segmentation fault
```

Comment: What is this "nil" you speak of? :-)

Comment: @Ed S. the printf %p specifier produces "(nil)" rather than address for my_struct_ptr in main.  I updated the question to help clarify for others. thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to pass the pointer as a pointer (i.e. pass its address):

```
int get_my_struct_by_name(char *name, struct my_struct **my_struct_ptr)
{                                                   // ^^^
    // ...
    *my_struct_ptr = /* ... */
}

int main()
{
    struct my_struct * my_struct_ptr;
    get_my_struct_by_name(name, &my_struct_ptr);
    // ...
}
```

If you just pass the pointer by value, as you did, you only modify a local copy of the pointer, not the original pointer.

Moral: If you want a function to change a variable in the calling scope, you have to say `&` somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

The solution is to use **pointer to pointer** in your function `get_my_struct_by_name`.
Notice addition `*` (asterisk) in the declaration, then in assignment (inside `get_my_struct_by_name`) and `&` ampersand in invokation (inside `main`). This way you are passing a pointer to your `my_struct_ptr` defined in `main` and assigning the right value directly to your variable in `main`.

This solution assumes that you are using pure C (in C++ having a reference to a pointer would be probably more convenient).

```
int get_my_struct_by_name(char *name, struct my_struct **my_struct_ptr)
{
    int i;
    for(i=0; i < (sizeof(my_structs)/sizeof(struct my_struct)); i++)
    {
        if(strcmp(name, my_structs[i].name) == 0)
        {
            *my_struct_ptr = &my_structs[i];
            printf("works: %s,%s,%s\n", my_struct_ptr->name, my_struct_ptr->descr,     
                   my_struct_ptr->value);
            return 0;
        }
    }

    return -1;
}


int main()
{
    int res = 0;
    struct my_struct *my_struct_ptr;

    if (res = get_my_struct_by_name("b", &my_struct_ptr))
        return res;

    printf( "nil: %p\n", my_struct_ptr);

    printf("seg fault: %s,%s,%s\n", my_struct_ptr->name, my_struct_ptr->descr, 
    my_struct_ptr->value);
    return res;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I recall correctly, you need to pass the address of the pointer and then dereference it inside of the routine. Since this is call by value, you need the **address of the pointer passed** to set the value of the pointer. I have update the routines below.

```
int get_my_struct_by_name(char *name, struct my_struct **my_struct_ptr) 
{      
    int i;    
    for (i=0; i < (sizeof(my_structs)/sizeof(struct my_struct)); i++) 
    {             
        if (strcmp(name, my_structs[i].name) == 0) 
        {                      
           *my_struct_ptr = &my_structs[i];
           printf("works: %s,%s,%s\n", my_struct_ptr->name, 
                   my_struct_ptr->descr, my_struct_ptr->value);
           return 0;             
        }     
    }      
 return -1; 
}
```

and then you need to take the address of the pointer and pass it in from the main routine.

```
if (res = get_my_struct_by_name("b", &my_struct_ptr))                 
   return res;
```

That way you can pass back the address of the structure.