# Setting a pointer value inside a function

Tags: c, pointers, pass-by-reference

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [void pointer as argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12448977/void-pointer-as-argument)

I'm trying to make a simple function in C, but I get an empty output and I can't figure out why:

```
int encrypt(unsigned char *message, char *key,  unsigned char *buffered_message)
{
    /* ... */

    buffered_message = calloc(1, (blocks * block_size));

    /* ... */

    printf("Message: %s\n", buffered_message);

    return strlen(buffered_message);
}
```

Inside the function, the message is printed out without problems. But when I try to use my function in `main`, something goes wrong.

```
int main()
{
    /* ... */

    unsigned char *encrypted;

    int len = encrypt(message, key, encrypted);

    if (len > 0)
    {
        printf("The encrypted message  %s\n", encrypted);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: [See here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12059728/596781). That answer applies verbatim to your `buffered_message`. Further duplicates: [#1](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11966454/596781), [#2](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11926448/596781), [#3](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9729853/596781).

Comment: @Kerrek So do I get this right, my buffered_message exists only in the function encrypt and thats why I cant use it in main? Sorry if it's a stupid question, but how can I get the encrypted message. I tryed to return buffered_message in encrypt, but then I get: warning: return makes pointer from integer without a cast

Comment: You have to pass a pointer to the pointer and dereference it in the function. Like I explained in every one of my other answers. You need to change the argument type to `unsigned char **`.

Comment: I've taken the liberty to trim your question down to the important content.

Comment: Oh, by the way, `strlen` looks dodgy. The encrypted message may well contain null bytes. Since you're encrypting entire blocks anyway, there shouldn't be a need to communicate a string length, since the caller already *knows* the expected length.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass double pointer since you are allocating memory and copying to the pointer local to the function.

The following should work, though i haven't compiled.

```
int encrypt(unsigned char *message, char *key,  unsigned char **buffered_message)
{
    /* ... */
    *buffered_message = calloc(1, (blocks * block_size));
    /* ... */
    printf("Message: %s\n", *buffered_message);
    return strlen(*buffered_message);
}
```

From main

```
unsigned char *encrypted;
int len = encrypt(message, key, &encrypted);
printf("The encrypted message  %s\n", encrypted);
```

Comment: And yes, as already mentioned, using strlen is a bad idea on an encrypted message because strlen would return length upto first \0, which might be very common in an encrypted message.

Comment: The main function is wrong. You should define `unsigned char * encrypted` and then pass `&encrypted` to the function. Otherwise you end up dereferencing an unintialized pointer

Comment: @ArmenTsirunyan. Yeah i only second thought that, and was editing answer on the way. Thanks for confirming. Edited the answer

Comment: Thanks everybody. I guess I have to read a litle more about pointers to pointers. But I'm very greatfull to all of you, for answering so fast.